# How to get All Field (Column Name) in any Table(Like Account ,Lead) from SalesForce?

Tags: salesforce-id, c#

I don't have any idea about Salesforce. I need to get the **All column Name** from a **Table** in **SalesForce**. For example in `Account` table I need FieldNames like `MasterRecordId`, `Id` ,`AccountNumber`, `OwnerId`, etc,. they must be **json object**.
Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

**APEX code !**

First, create your Object :

```
public class Obj {
    List<String> objList {get; set;}

    public Obj(List<String> l) {
        objList = l;
    }
}
```

And then, loop on all fields, put them in a List and serialize your object (here test with Account object):

```
SObjectType objType = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('Account');
Map<String,Schema.SObjectField> objMap = objType.getDescribe().fields.getMap();
List<String> accList = new List<String>();

for (Schema.SObjectField f : objMap.values()) {
    Schema.DescribeFieldResult rfield = f.getDescribe();
    String n = rfield.getName();
    accList.add(n);
}

Obj o = new Obj(accList);
String jsonString = JSON.serialize(o);
```

Display your JSON object :

```
system.debug(LoggingLevel.WARN, jsonString);
```

To have this :

```
{"objList":["Id","IsDeleted","MasterRecordId","Name","Type","RecordTypeId","ParentId","BillingStreet","BillingCity","BillingState","BillingPostalCode","BillingCountry","BillingLatitude","BillingLongitude","BillingGeocodeAccuracy","BillingAddress",...]}
```

Comment: thanks. SObjectType and Schema is asking some reference.  what reference i have to add?

Comment: I don't understand ! Do you have an error message to show ?

Comment: No. it shows ` the Type or namespace name 'SObjectType '  could not be found.`

Comment: Did you put this code in a function, and then call it ?

Comment: yes.  i put this code inside the function

Comment: You put `C#` in tag. Do you code this in APEX or C# ?

Comment: i'm using c# code.

Comment: OK, this code is APEX code ... I let it for information but in your case, it won't be usefull...